# Is it possible to get a % of (name)/total using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if anyone knows how to get a % of say dctest/In using VBA excel?
dctest for this example is just some tested perimeter while the In can be considered as the total number of devices set to do the dc test.

I have provided an image for better understanding. Both set of results shown are before and after converting the values into %. What i'm required will be finding the % of all tests except for test1-test6. The denominator will be values of In, ie, dctest/In.

[image]

I have tried some coding, but am not very sure of how to get the percentage of the values.

```
Sub macro1()
    Dim testrow As Long, testcell As Range, lastrowval As Long

    testrow = 1 'initialise
    Do
        Set testcell = Sheets("Summary").Cells(testrow, 1)
        'To look for any test1-test6, if there is do nothing
        If testcell = "test1" Or testcell = "test2" Or testcell = "test3" Or testcell = "test4" Or testcell = "test5" Or testcell = "test6" Then
            'Do nothing
            Exit Do
        End If
        testrow = testrow + 1
    Loop
    Do
        Set testcell = Sheets("Summary").Cells(testrow, 1)
        If testcell = "Resultant" Then
            lastrowval = testrow
            Exit Do
        End If
        testrow = testrow + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Do take note that, I'm aware of the use of the fixed formula that excel can do, but at times some of the tests such as ACtest will not be there OR there will be an extra test such as morning test, this will affect the fixed formula.

Do take note also that test1 - test6, sometimes all 6 tests will be present, at times only 1 test will be present.

What my concern is if there is an extra test say test1 added in, the row from dctest..... Resultant will be shifted down by 1 row.

And if there is a test say test6 got removed, the row from dctest.... resultant will be shifted up by 1 row. I'm not very sure what can be done to make sure this issues can be solved.

Follow up

[image]

Comment: why not just use a formula for `J7` of `=$B7/$B$1` and format the cell as % and copy to `J8`..`J11`?.

Comment: i have thought of that, but at times some of the tests such as actest will not be there or there will be an extra test like morningtest, it will affect the fixed formula.. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken the same example as shown in the picture. Like your previous question, you can either use a formula or a code.

**Formula**

In Cell J7, enter this formula and then right click on the cell to format as %age.

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(INDEX(MATCH(I7,$A$1:$A$11,0),1,0),1,1,1)),0,1)/$B$1
```

If you need then simply copy the formula down

**Code**

```
Sub Sample()
    With Range("J7")
        .FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(INDEX(MATCH(RC[-1],R1C1:R11C1,0),1,0),1,1,1)),0,1)/R1C2"
        .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    End With
End Sub
```

OR

```
Sub Sample()
    With Range("J7")
        .Formula = _
        "=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(INDEX(MATCH(I7,$A$1:$A$11,0),1,0),1,1,1)),0,1)/$B$1"
        .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    End With
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim SearchText As String, Excludetext As String
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim MyArray() As String
    Dim boolContinue As Boolean

    '~~> Add/Remove the text here which you want to ignore
    Excludetext = "In,Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5,Test6"

    MyArray = Split(Excludetext, ",")

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = ws.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To LastRow
        boolContinue = True

        For j = 0 To UBound(MyArray)
            SearchText = Ucase(Trim(MyArray(j)))
            If Ucase(Trim(ws.Range("I" & i).Value)) = SearchText Then
                boolContinue = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j

        If boolContinue = True Then
            With Range("J" & i)
                .Formula = _
                "=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(INDEX(MATCH(I" & i & _
                ",$A$1:$A$11,0),1,0),1,1,1)),0,1)/$B$1"
                .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
            End With
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

HTH

Sid

Comment: Hi Sid, i'm not sure " ,0),1,0),1,1,1)),0,1 " what this line did and it somehow did not show any result, instead a #N/A was displayed. And btw, the tests of test1-test6, at times, there maybe all of the 6 tests and at times there may only be 1 tests, so if using the With range ("J7") I may get an inaccurate result.

Comment: Here is a sample document. http://wikisend.com/download/231382/user1204868_Sample.xlsx

Comment: Thanks for the upload but i have 1 concern still, which is what if the tests for this particular example, test2-test6, all are being removed and left with just test6, the length of the set of values will be different, then what can i do to get an accurate answer?

Comment: The formula is independent of those values in one way. We are calculating "dctest/IN". If "IN" changes because of test1-test6 then you will get different values

Comment: If "IN" is fixed then you will get same values every time for "dctest/IN". BTW, I am stepping out for 1 hour so might not be able to respond to your comment. Will have a look when I come back.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what i'm trying to say in my previous comment. What I'm trying to say is, if i were to use the VBA codes and set it for this particular example, it will definitely get the % i want, but what if say I remove one of the tests say test6, dctest.... Resultant will get shifted up 1 row, which means I will be a redundant % result after resultant. Another case would be if I were to add in test1, dctest ... Resultant will be shifted down by 1, and the test6 for instance will have a % instead and Resultant will not have any % values.. I hope this helps you see what i'm trying

Comment: Ah I see what you mean :) In that case you will have to adjust the formula in the code, the formula still remains the same :) Let me show you an example for dctest. I will post the code shortly.

Comment: i have tried the code, it is working... but one question will be for the subsequent tests, i need to do the same thing? Look for search text before i can have the result? If so, what if I'm unsure of the name of the text, how can it be done?

Comment: In such a scenario would it help if inserts the formulas for all text except for test1-test6?

Comment: Ya. I think so, and also ignore the 'In'.. I have tried modifying the code without SearchText with the "<> "test1" and so on ". But it tabulates the result for 'In' even using the <>

Comment: Ok The post has been Updated!

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I have 1 last question, i hope you dont mind. What if I have a subsequent column at C, and i want to do the same thing?

Comment: What do you mean by "subsequent column at C"?

Comment: I have added another picture of what i mean. Another set of values found in column C..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7907/discussion-between-user1204868-and-siddharth-rout)

Comment: Hi, i was wondering if that code u given.. can it still do matching if it is comparing between 2 different sheets.. which means the values are not in the same sheet. but they are duplicated into another sheet. but i need to do matching.. i hope u can see this message

Comment: Yes. I would suggest continuing it in a new post as this post is already closed and also the comments are getting already quite long.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just turn it into a percent part/whole=x/100